# can anyone look this python error :an illegal target for a variable annotation

Tags: python

Hard to believe this simple code doesn't run.
Can anyone help with it please.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've misspelled `if` as `If`.

Comment: And also please copy text rather than images for future issues - thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change the `If` to lowercase, to `if`

You also need to replace `elif` with `else` since `elif` would not be used in this situation, `else` would. `elif` is used when the first condition is false, and the specified `elif` condition is true. `else` is used when just the first condition is false, with no other true condition.

Here's the fixed code:

```
n = 1

if n > 25:
    print("1")
else:
    print("0")
```

(It gives no error in VSCode)

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions caused by a typo. They are not suitable for the site, and answers interfere with [automatic cleanup processes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).